# Can't execute "cat" using system() function in C

Tags: c, bash, posix, system, cat

I have a function that is the handler of the SIGINT signal in my C program, that when is executed should simply execute the following commands:

```
void sigint_handler(int sig)
  {
    system("cat output.txt");
    exit(0);
  }
```

The problem is that the "cat" command doesn't seems to do anything. If I try to do something else instead of "cat", like "echo something" it works fine, so I believe the problem is with the "cat" and not with the system() function.
The file "output.txt" is in the same directory of the C program, and if I try to execute cat on that file through another C script it works. Also if I try to execute that command from shell it works.

I've checked the return from the `system("cat output.txt")` and it's 0. So what can the problem be?

EDIT: The file output.txt is also open as a FILE stream (using `fopen()`) in the program, by another thread, could that be an issue maybe?

Comment: You should know that signal handlers can only safely call a restricted set of [async-signal-safe functions](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). Neither `system()` nor `exit()` are on the list.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I saw this from my professor, so I thought it was legit. In his version of the program he declares the signal handler with `signal(SIGINT, handler)` and then calls the `system("cat output.txt")` from there.

Comment: he's declaring the signal handler correctly. But the functions that `sigint_handler()` uses are restricted.

Comment: Yep, no surprise there. It's a common mistake and professors are human beings. You should tell him; hopefully he'll appreciate the info.

Comment: Ok, I see, but I don't understand why his version is working while mine is not. I declare the signal handler in the same way, but my program can't execute that "cat" command, while in his version it does.

Comment: @twentywhilepython, are you sure you're testing on the same platform as your professor? Sometimes things that aren't guaranteed still work despite not being guaranteed as an accident of environment or configuration. That doesn't make the code that just happens to work correct; good code relies only on documented, guaranteed semantics.

Comment: Did you check to run your program with `strace` (or `truss` or similar)?

Comment: It doesn't sound like this is the problem, but just in case: the filename `output.txt` will be resolved in the `cat` process's working directory, which is inherited from your program's working directory, which is inherited from whatever process executed your program (probably a shell?) (unless your program runs `chdir()` or something). Are you in the same directory as `output.txt` when you run the program?

Comment: By your logic `cat` should only print output.txt if it is located in the same directory as cat.  The current directory of the process is not related to where the program is.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, I'm testing them on the same pc, if I run his code it works, mine don't unfortunately. And yes, output.txt is in the same directory where my program runs. In fact if I write another simple program in the same dir just to execute that cat command it works.

Comment: Re: the file being also opened by your running program -- if you're on a POSIXy platform, no, that won't cause any problem at all. As for digging into why one program appears to work and another doesn't, we'd need a [mre] to build a testable answer -- but in general, questions about undefined behavior get "don't do that" as an answer, and this is widely considered proper; if you're relying on undefined behavior, things will break eventually, even if it only happens after an OS update or such; building reliable, production-ready software means writing to documented semantics only [...].

Comment: [...], and avoiding doing something just because it _looks like_ it works, if the documentation doesn't guarantee that it will.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should know that signal handlers can only safely call a restricted set of [async-signal-safe functions](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). Neither `system()` nor `exit()` are on the list. Calling them is likely to trigger undefined behavior, which can lead to unpredictable results.

[You say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049208/cant-execute-cat-using-system-function-in-c#comment120274950_68049208):

> I see, but I don't understand why his version is working while mine is not. I declare the signal handler in the same way, but my program can't execute that "cat" command, while in his version it does.

I second [Charles Duffy's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049208/cant-execute-cat-using-system-function-in-c#comment120275022_68049208):

> Sometimes things that aren't guaranteed still work despite not being guaranteed as an accident of environment or configuration. That doesn't make the code that just happens to work correct; good code relies only on documented, guaranteed semantics.

A common workaround for this is to move your signal handling code to the main program, and have the main program periodically check a [global variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/sig_atomic_t). From the signal handler all would do is set the global variable and return. This technique will let you do whatever you like, albeit in a somewhat convoluted way.

```
volatile sig_atomic_t sigint_received = 0;

void sigint_handler(int sig)
{  
  sigint_received = 1;
}
```

```
// main program loop
for (;;) {
  // do stuff
  ...

  // check for interruption
  if (sigint_received) {
    system("cat output.txt");
    ​exit(0);
  }
}
```